# Ocean displacement map not showing waves, even with enough faces

Tags: modifiers

Already found tons of similar posts and the answer is always the same: add more geometry...but I already have 4000 faces and even with 16000 faces, still no waves. The only thing changing is the z-position of the plane. Does anyone knows how it works?

I cannot believe that. I tried every parameter except scale...thanks! and scale to 1

[Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgxOoYbGHXtygYdagAoidvXnH9rUoQ?e=vRw0Qf)

[image]

Comment: Hello there! Seems to be a problem with Scale - it is set to 0.

Comment: If I set my Geometry Size to what you have (35) my waves disappear.  Try setting to 1 and then increase gradually to what you need.   What is size?  blender doc gives no detail, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

As Einstein's Minion pointed out, you have the scale set to 0. Increasing to around 4 seems to give a pretty substantial effect. As others have also mentioned, adding more geometry helps, so I added a Subdivision Surface Modifier to the top of the modifier stack for the purpose of this example. This should really be all that's necessary to make the waves show properly:

[image: Scaled]